# Ideas how to design a table/chart on a double paged spread of a thick book so it's readable and looks awesome

Tags: print-design, typesetting, tables, chart-design

I am designing a double page spread for a thick catalogue. It will have over 150 pages which means the binding will take some space from the middle.

This is how it looks now:
[image: Screenshot]

The I'am looking for inspiration on how to set the table so it is readable, despite the binding take some aways from the page. I decided to solve it by splitting the table, but that way the reader might loose the row... I am also looking for inspiration on how to make a big chart like this better readable.

Does anyone know a forum or a website where I can find inspiration of table designs?

Have a great day!

Comment: What are the dimensions of the page? And the inner margins? They look very narrow. I think the left and right part of the table look disconnected because they are not the same height.

Comment: The pages are A4 so 210 × 297 mm each. The Inner margins of the table are 2 mm. Okay got it back together now. This is how it looks like now: https://imgur.com/a/35YvjMC

Comment: You can edit your question to update the image. What I meant was the inner margin of the *pages*. The distance from the spine to the text content of the table. Looks like you have about 4-6 mm only (different on left and right page). That's way too little to ensure the text doesn't disappear into the spine. You'll probably need 10-20 mm to be sure. Like you have on the main text. It's good that the whole table now has uniform height and I think it's also good that the horizontal lines of the table go across the spread. You can't be sure they will align 100% on print though.

Comment: I'm just commenting here as I'm unsure if the question is too broad to answer. Might be closed as "opinion-based". You need to somehow narrow it down to a specific question instead of asking for ideas and inspiration.

Comment: All right, changed the table thank you!

Comment: Can you flip it 90 degrees?

Comment: Any reason why one couldn't do the full table on one page, and the text on the opposing page?

Comment: Rather than rotating the table, you could transpose it: turn columns into rows and vice versa (sorry, @steve, if that’s what you meant).  If the resulting table is too long for one page, you can break it across pages (repeating the column titles) so the reader doesn’t have to scan a row across both pages.